# macOS 10.14 kernel debugging

Tags: macos, lldb, macos-mojave

I'm trying to use lldb for kernel debugging on a macOS 10.14 machine
I set my nvram boot-args="debug=0x144 -v" and while pressing the keys combo and sending an NMI I attach lldb and when pressing 'c' to resume, the machine is still frozen, and cannot resume.

is there anything I'm doing wrong here?
this method has worked fine until 10.14

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the exact same problem. Couldn't resolve it with NMI, but there's another way to trigger lldb that supports continuing after. Using

```
sudo dtrace -w -n "BEGIN { breakpoint(); }"
```

from the guest machine should do the trick. Be aware that you must **disable SIP** for this to work.